# hibernate and spring dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two tables Parent and Child.
Child table references to Parent table.

In application configuration of spring dao. Can't I give configuration of only child?
like below.

```
<bean id="ChildDAOSpringTarget" class="project.dao.spring.ChildDAOSpring">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ChildDAO"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="ChildDAOSpringTarget" />
    </property>

    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="store*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="add*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

***Do I have to have add this kind of configuration and classes for Parent even?***

Answer (score 0):

I don't config relation between parent and child table in applicationContext.xml but I set the relation in modelXXX.hbm.xml file or you can use hibernate tools to generate model [link](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate, parent-child relationship has been defined in hbm file or it will be annotation based. And in application configuration file, you have to define database connection's properties, session factory, bean mapping etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yep as mentioned above... Check here for one to many tutorial which is likely what you are trying to do. 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/
The child becomes a collection of the parent and is accessed as such.
Spring doesn't need to reference the child - instead you reference the children through the parent like so:
     parent.getChildren().[...]